# How to generate Azure app token using client id and client secret using SPFx with react.js (webpart)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, azure, microsoft-graph, sharepoint-app-registration

I am trying to generate the azure app token using client id and client secret.

Please find my below code:

```
 const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("grant_type ", "client_credentials");
    formData.append(
        "client_id ",
        "{client ID}@{Tenentid}"
    );
    formData.append(
        "client_secret ",
        "{Client secreat}"
    );
    formData.append(
        "resource ",
        "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/{Tenentname}.sharepoint.com@{TenentID}"
    );
    //  await axios.request(options).then((response) =>
    // context.res.json({
    //   itemCount: response.data.length,
    //   items: response.data,
    // })
    const msurl =
        "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{TenentID}/tokens/OAuth/2";

    axios.post(msurl, formData)
        .then((response) => {
        })
```

facing the below issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{tenentid}/tokens/OAuth/2' from origin 'https://{tenentname}.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please let me know any alternative approach or fix to get the token.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585377/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-https-login-microsoftonline-com-has-been-blocked-b) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/418904/error-access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-httprom-origin-h). Let me know if it works for you.